# Can't build a Rust Rocket Webserver that accepts POST request

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

I have a problem when creating a web server with Rocket in Rust. ❌

I followed this guide: https://betterprogramming.pub/creating-a-web-server-using-rust-rocket-1e4939e582df

I have a super simple program:

```
#[macro_use] extern crate rocket;

use rocket::serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};
use rocket::serde::json::Json;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(crate = "rocket::serde")]
pub struct PersonEntity {
    name: &'static str,
    age: u8,
}

#[post("/", format = "json", data= "<new_person>")]
pub fn add_person(new_person: Json<PersonEntity>) -> Json<PersonEntity> {
    Json(PersonEntity {name: "peter", age: 33})
}

#[launch]
fn rocket() -> _ {
    rocket::build()
        .mount("/person", routes![
            add_person
        ])
}
```

Somehow two errors on the same thing (see also screenshots).

```
error[E0521]: borrowed data escapes outside of function
  --> src/person/person_controller.rs:10:31
   |
9  | #[post("/", format = "json", data= "<new_person>")]
   | ---------------------------------------------------
   | |
   | `__req` is a reference that is only valid in the function body
   | lifetime `'__r` defined here
10 | pub fn add_person(new_person: Json<PersonEntity>) -> Json<PersonEntity> {
   |                               ^^^^
   |                               |
   |                               `__req` escapes the function body here
   |                               argument requires that `'__r` must outlive `'static`
```

Does anybody have an idea what's the issue? Thank you!

[first error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZV29a.png)
[second error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IMJD.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @cafce25 thank you for the hint and the edit.

Comment: Try replacing your `&'static str` with a simpler `String`. I think the JSON deserializer is trying to give you slices of the request buffer, but your `'static` declaration makes that impossible to do.

Comment: @rodrigo you made my day! It now works. Thanks! The error message was so cryptic that I (as a newbie) couldn't get much out of it.